# Two states for same URL in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following routing set up in my app:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('splash',
    {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'all': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/splash.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('home',
    {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'all': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('contents',
    {
        url: '/contents',
        views: {
            'all': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/contents.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

So the user sees the splash page when the app first loads and then clicks a button in the splash template that loads the home state. This allows me to have a state that has no history or URL so the user CAN'T return to the splash page via the browser back button (unless they refresh the page).

The problem is that when the user then navigates to the contents page (again via a button on the home page), this creates a history entry and allows the user to return (which is fine), but hitting the back button takes the user back to the splash state instead of the home state...

How can I stop this?

Comment: can use `resolve` and reject it based on some user or application state stored in a service

Comment: Can this be somewhat hacked? On first visit to splash, you save a variable (globally / in a service) which counts amount of times page has been viewed. Then any subsequent call to splash would look at the counter and determine whether to show the page or not. You can even use templateUrl as a function to return a different template so that home and splash become the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm not seeing a controller declared in the states above, I'm assuming your templates declare the controller. So.. you could change the templateUrl on the fly by saving data in a variable, here is a hack:

```
var splashVisits = 0;
localStorage.setItem('splashVisit', JSON.stringify(splashVisits )); // save this in a service actually or like so in localStorage when app loads
$stateProvider
    .state('splash',
    {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'all': {
                // make the template url a function which returns a different template based on number of splash visits.
                templateUrl: function(){
                    // read splashVisits
                    splashVisits = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('splashVisits')); // returns some value
                    if(splashVisits == 0){ 
                        splashVisits++;
                        localStorage.setItem('splashVisit', JSON.stringify(splashVisits ));
                        return 'partials/splash.html';
                    }
                    else 
                        return 'partials/home.html';
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

I haven't actually tried this myself, but I know templateUrl accepts a function. If you set up a plunker/jsfiddle that would help out with testing this.

**Update**

```
$stateProvider
.state('splash',
{
    url: '/',
    controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
        var ctrlName = null;
        splashVisits = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('splashVisits')); 
        if(splashVisits == 0){ 
            ctrlName = 'HomeCtrl';
        }
        return ctrlName;
    }
    views: {
        'all': {
            templateUrl: function(){
                // read splashVisits
                splashVisits = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('splashVisits')); // returns some value
                if(splashVisits == 0){ 
                    splashVisits++;
                    localStorage.setItem('splashVisit', JSON.stringify(splashVisits ));
                    return 'partials/splash.html';
                }
                else {
                    // force state change?
                    return 'partials/home.html';
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
.state('home', 
{ 
    url: '', 
    controller: 'HomeCtrl', 
    views: { 
        'all': { 
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html' 
        } 
    } 
})
.state('contents',
{
    url: '/contents',
    views: {
        'all': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/contents.html'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: How would I navigate to the `home` state though? As the state would be `splash` for both `splash` and `home` so when I click the button on the splash page it won't do anything as it's the same state (it'll never even fire the `splashVisits` code inside the `templateUrl` function as it won't see a statechange)

Comment: Unless your saying have both splash and home states but have the code in the splash state to allow it to render the home view as well?

Comment: Yes, the idea is the first time the splash page is hit, it should return the splash page template (and controller) and increment a counter. Then, when it hits splash the second time, you should return the home page.

Comment: But you'd still need the home state as well to navigate to!

Comment: I can't get it to set the localStorage via the controller though... I tried:  `phonecatControllers.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

 localStorage.setItem('splashVisits', JSON.stringify(1));

});`

Comment: And the home state has: `.state('home',
  {
   url: '',
   controller: 'HomeCtrl',
   views: {
    'all': {
     templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    }
   }
  })`

Comment: Can you set up a plunker/jsFiddle? I'd like to help out.

Comment: This works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198345/two-states-for-same-url-in-angularjs/28199092#28199092

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @SoluableNonagon

This code solves the problem:

```
var splashVisits = 0;
localStorage.setItem('splashVisits', JSON.stringify(splashVisits));

$stateProvider
    .state('splash',
    {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'all': {
                templateUrl: function(){

                    splashVisits = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('splashVisits'));

                    if(splashVisits > 0) {
                        return 'partials/home.html';
                    }
                    else {
                        splashVisits++;
                        localStorage.setItem('splashVisits', JSON.stringify(splashVisits));
                        return 'partials/splash.html';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .state('home',
    {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'all': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
            }
        }
    })
```